# Mysql query for getting listing of student that has no courses in month 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to query those students who has no course in month 3.

Here are the tables:

**studends:**

[image]

**courses:**

[image]

I have tried this query so far:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(s.id)) as studentIdWithNotCourse, s.name FROM students as s left join courses as c on c.studentId = s.id WHERE c.id IS NULL group by s.name
```

Now this query gives me those students whose entry doesn't exists in courses table.

Now the thing I am not getting is how or where can I apply that condition where I can say that I need those students who either has no record in courses table or that student doesnt have any course in month == 3

Comment: Does 'Grammer' include spelling?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `count(DISTINCT s.id)`, to make code clearer.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. (Make it easy to copy-and-paste!)

Comment: And why are you counting stuff?

Comment: Please supply a [minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to query those students who has no course in month 3.

This suggests `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from students s
where not exists (select 1
                  from courses c
                  where c.studentid = s.studentid and c.month = 3
                 );
```